# Adding data to column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

i have written this query to show total working time and overtime of an employee on particular date (if he has came). i want if for a particular date person's INtime and OutTime are empty then put 00:00 in his intime, outtime, totalworkingtime, overtime e.g. it's sunday so obviously no InTime and OutTime then it should show 00:00 in time columns.
Note: dates are only entered if person InTIme is mentioned otherwise no DateVisited.

e.g.

```
EmplID  EmplName ShiftID intime Outtime totalworking overtime  dateVisited
0000001 John     S001    00:00  00:00   00:00:       00:00     2013-12-01
```

Query:

```
with times as (

SELECT    t1.EmplID

        , t3.EmplName

        , min(t1.RecTime) AS InTime

        , max(t2.RecTime) AS [TimeOut]

        , t4.ShiftId as ShiftID

        , t4.StAtdTime as ShStartTime

        , t4.EndAtdTime as ShEndTime

        , cast(min(t1.RecTime) as datetime) AS InTimeSub

        , cast(max(t2.RecTime) as datetime) AS TimeOutSub

        , t1.RecDate AS [DateVisited]

FROM  AtdRecord t1 

INNER JOIN 

      AtdRecord t2 

ON    t1.EmplID = t2.EmplID 

AND   t1.RecDate = t2.RecDate

AND   t1.RecTime < t2.RecTime

inner join 

      HrEmployee t3 

ON    t3.EmplID = t1.EmplID 

inner join AtdShiftSect t4

ON t3.ShiftId = t4.ShiftId

group by 

          t1.EmplID

        , t3.EmplName

        , t1.RecDate

        , t4.ShiftId 

        , t4.StAtdTime 

        , t4.EndAtdTime

)
SELECT 

 EmplID

,EmplName
,ShiftId As ShiftID

,InTime
,[TimeOut]
,convert(char(5),cast([TimeOutSub] - InTimeSub as time), 108) TotalWorkingTime

,[DateVisited]
,CASE WHEN [InTime] IS NOT NULL AND [TimeOut] IS NOT NULL THEN

     CONVERT(char(5),CASE WHEN  CAST([TimeOutSub] AS DATETIME) >= ShEndTime And ShiftID = 'S002' Then  LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(12), DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(ms, CAST(ShEndTime AS DATETIME),CAST([TimeOutSub] AS DATETIME)),0), 108),5) 

                          WHEN  CAST([TimeOutSub] AS DATETIME) >= ShEndTime And ShiftID = 'S001' Then  LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(12), DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(ms, CAST(ShEndTime AS DATETIME),  CAST([TimeOutSub] AS DATETIME)),0), 108),5) 

      ELSE '00:00' END, 108) 

 ELSE 'ABSENT' END AS OverTime

FROM times  order by EmplID, ShiftID, DateVisited
```

Comment: You've got a `CASE` statement already, what's the problem here?

Comment: Problem is that for holidays i should mention 00:00 in time sections

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm just needing more coffee.  How do we know that it's a holiday?

Comment: that's the problem, that's the actual problem sir

Comment: sir there must be any way to get around it ? i have wasted several hours trying it but couldn't please help

Comment: I still don't understand.  Are you saying that any day where the individual does not have an `InTime` should be considered a holiday?

Comment: yes @tommy_o like this

Answer (score 1):

If your problem solely relies on knowing when a date is a workday/holiday/weekend I would recommend using a DataWarehouse solution. Create A table that contains all the holidays/weekends and check against it.

Depending on what Calendar and what other dates you are using there are many scripts out there to create it for you, but the simplest way would be for the next 10 years or so calculate when all your holidays land on. for example Christmas is always on December 23 and thanksgiving is always 3 week in November I would create a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE Holiday
(
HolidayID INT NOT NULL, --surrogate key, but you can just as easily make HolidayDate the Natural key
HolidayDate  DATE NOT NULL
HolidayName NVARCHAR(30),--encase you need non English holiday names saved
...
...
..


INSERT INTO Holiday (HolidayDate,HolidayName) VALUES (2014-12-23, 'Christmas')
INSERT INTO Holiday (HolidayDate,HolidayName) VALUES (2015-12-23, 'Christmas')
INSERT INTO Holiday (HolidayDate,HolidayName) VALUES (2016-12-23, 'Christmas')
INSERT INTO Holiday (HolidayDate,HolidayName) VALUES (2017-12-23, 'Christmas')
.....
.....
....
```

Or if you want to get even  more indepth you can map out ever day for the next 10 years in a table (Date Dimension table). Then mark those days as holidays, work cancelled, sales quarters and what not. (google Date Dimension Table)

Comment: how sir i couldn't understand this

Comment: What is confusing you, when can go over it step by step if you would like